# How can I write a simple query for FILL IN hide?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have written a sample query for hide more than 11 fill in box but the way is not satisfied. I don't like assigning YES to all instead need to go for a simple way.

```
DO  WITH FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}: 
ASSIGN
     ParaName:HIDDEN = YES
     ParaValue1:HIDDEN = YES
     ParaValue2:HIDDEN = YES
     ParaMaint:HIDDEN = YES
     RECT-12:HIDDEN   = YES
     RECT-13:HIDDEN   = YES
     btnEdit:HIDDEN = YES
     btnSave:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName1:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName2:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName3:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName4:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName5:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName6:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName7:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName8:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName9:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName10:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName11:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName12:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName13:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName14:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName15:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName16:HIDDEN = YES 
     TBParaName17:HIDDEN = YES
     TBParaName18:HIDDEN = YES
END.
```

Comment: Your example does not compile.

Comment: What is the poor idea that has been exposed?  All I can guess is that maybe you don't like assigning YES to a lot of fields?

Comment: Yes Sir. assigning YES to all fields exposed me as poor programmer

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
def var tb as logical no-undo extent 5 view-as toggle-box.

define frame fr
   tb[1] label "1"
   tb[2] label "2" 
   tb[3] label "3" 
   tb[4] label "4"  
   tb[5] label "5"   
   .

do with frame fr:

   def var hw as handle no-undo.

   enable all.

   hw = frame fr:handle:first-child. /* field-group */
   hw = hw:first-child.
   do while valid-handle( hw ) and hw:type = "toggle-box":
     if integer( hw:label ) modulo 2 = 0 then /* or use hw:name or whatever */
         hw:visible = false.
      hw = hw:next-sibling.
   end.

end.

wait-for close of frame fr.
```